# MySQL insert conditional datetime

Tags: mysql, datetime, date, time, insert

I 'm wondering if it possible to insert records based on a specific date/time in one query without first selecting it.

For example:

I want to insert only when there is no record from 2 minutes ago.

How would this be achieved?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following statement instead of `INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (1,'foobar')`:

```
INSERT INTO foobar (foobar_id,display_name,ctime)
SELECT 42,'foobar',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
FROM DUAL
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM foobar
    WHERE mtime > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() - INTERVAL 2 MINUTE
);
```

The trick is: Find a select statement, that returns a row with the columns to insert, if and only if the row should be inserted - and finally put `INSERT INTO table_name` in front of it. Note that the table `DUAL` is special table in MySQL and other DBMS.

Comment: Could you expend you answer with an example of foo data?

Comment: Where do you leave the variables to be inserted? ( the VALUES() )

Comment: @John: The values to be inserted are `42` and `'foobar'`.